# Proving by induction $5^{3n} + 2 \cdot 5^{2n} - 5^{n} - 2$ is divisible by $4$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I want to prove the following twice. Once by induction then again by any other method.
$$5^{3n} + 2 \cdot 5^{2n} - 5^{n} - 2$$ is a multiple of 4 for all nonnegative integers n.

Let n=0 , since it is the first nonnegative integer

$$5^{3(0)}+2*5^{2(0)}-5^{0}-2 = 0 $$

Factoring gives us $(5-1)(5+1)(5+2)$

Comment: did you thought about factorizing it ?

Comment: It means a multiple of $4$ i.e. $4\times n$ rather than a power of $4$, which would be $4^n$. I can prove this twice without induction: working modulo $4$ or finding a factor $(5-1)$ - personally I would't use induction for this unless I had to.

Comment: @Mark (5-1)(5+1)(5+2) is the factor I get. Is this right? If so how would you proceed?

Comment: Since $5-1=4$ you have a factor $4$ and don't have to worry about the rest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basis(n=1):  $5^3+50-5-2=168 = 4*42$

Inductive step: assume that $5^{3n}+2*5^{2n}-5^n+1 = 4k, k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then,

$$
5*(5^{3n})+10*{5^{2n}}-5*5^n + 1 = 5(5^{3n}+2*5^{2n}-5^n)+1 = 5(4k-1)+1=20k-4=4(5k-1).
$$

Comment: Shouldn't we start with n=0 in our base case... for the first nonnegative integer? @Vinícius

Comment: Yeah,for n=0, the expression is $0$, which is a multiple of 4, but that is not very fun, is it?

Comment: @ViníciusNovelli I have to admit that I don't understand your induction answer. Is there something obvious that I'm missing? To understand why I don't get it, please look at my answer below (on which I'm probably fixated and might be the result of my misunderstanding the question). Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** for induction step

$$ 5^{3(n+1)}+2\cdot 5^{2(n+1)} -5^{n+1}-2 $$
$$= 5^{3n}\cdot(124+1)+2\cdot 5^{2n}\cdot(24+1) -5^{n}\cdot(4+1)-2$$

$$= (5^{3n}+2\cdot 5^{2n} -5^{n}-2) +   (5^{3n}\cdot 124+2\cdot 5^{2n}\cdot 24 -5^{n}\cdot 4) $$

$$= (5^{3n}+2\cdot 5^{2n} -5^{n}-2) +   4\cdot (5^{3n}\cdot 31+2\cdot 5^{2n}\cdot 6 -5^{n}). $$

Answer (score 1):

$$5^{3n} + 2 \cdot5^{2n} - 5^{n} - 2=5^n\cdot5^{2n}+2 \cdot5^{2n} - 5^{n} - 2=$$
$$5^{2n}( 5^{n} +2)-( 5^{n}+2)=( 5^{n} + 2)(5^{2n} - 1)=$$
$$=( 5^{n} + 2)(5^{n} + 1)(5^{n} -1)$$

Comment: Yes exactly so (5-1) is obviously divisible by 4 and from what Mark said we don't care about the other two factors. How do I explicitly show that my proof has come 'full circle' if you will.

Answer (score 1):

$$5^{3n} + 2 \cdot 5^{2n} - 5^{n} - 2=(5^n+2)(5^{2n}-1)=(5^n+2)(5^n-1)(5^n+1)$$
Do you see middle term is divisible by $4$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: write $5=4+1$ and use the binomial theorem.

Comment: You know my first thought was to use binomial theorem/expansion but I think modulo would have been easier for me

Comment: @mar10, if you can use modular arguments, then it follows at once because $5\equiv 1\bmod 4$.